# Issue with fancyimpute installation in Window 64

Tags: fancyimpute

I am trying to install fancyimpute from Anaconda prompt but running to below errors. There are lot of messages in the prompt but I have provided only error messages.

```
 building '_cvxcore' extension
  error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cvxpy
  Running setup.py clean for cvxpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scs ... done
  Running setup.py clean for scs
Failed to build cvxpy scs
```

and also this error at last

```
Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building '_cvxcore' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
```

Edit:
Resolution: I was using visual Studio community 2015. After installing visual studio community 2017 issue is resolved. I am able to successfully install fancyimpute and using it.

Comment: Do you have that path? Is your Visual Studio version different?

Comment: @JamesZ there is no such path. I have Visual Studio 2015 but I have read here in another post that installing Visual Studio 2017 community will solve. I update here after installation.

Comment: @JamesZ After installing Visual Studio 2017 issue has been resolved.